# Add headers and payload in requests.put

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab

I am trying to use requests in a Python3 script to update a deploy key in a gitlab project with write access. Unfortunately, I am receiving a 404 error when trying to connect via the requests module. The code is below:

```
project_url = str(url)+('/deploy_keys/')+str(DEPLOY_KEY_ID)
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN" : "REDACTED"}
    payload = {"can_push" : "true"}

    r = requests.put(project_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    print(r)
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong where in the syntax of my Private Key/headers?

I have gone through gitlab api and requests documentation. I have also confirmed that my Private Token is working outside of the script.

I am expecting it to update the deploy key with write access, but am receiving a  upon exit, making me think the issue is with the headers/auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved, it was actually not an auth problem. You must use the project ID instead of url, for example:

```
project_url = f'https://git.REDACTED.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/deploy_keys/{DEPLOY_KEY_ID}'
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN" : "REDACTED"}
    payload = {'can_push' : 'true'}

    try:
        r = requests.put(project_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```